# How to recognize touch the view on the back which is not in hierarchy?

Tags: ios, swift, touch

I have **MainVC** view which is not linked to **SetupVC** view.

(*Both VC are tableViewController, and the MainVC is splitView master-detail.*)

I display **SetupVC** programmatically.

**SetupVC** is a rootview of a navigation controller that has segue to **OtherVC** view.

[image]

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(dismissVC))
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
tap.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

I had this code in viewDidLoad in **SetupVC** and it seems only to recognize touch within **SetupVC**.

I'm trying to tap **MainVC** and it did not recognize.

[image]

Please help advise, I'd like to recognize touch outside and behind **SetupVC** to dismiss **SetupVC**.

In this case, is to recognize the touch on the **MainVC** which is in the back of **SetupVC**.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you upload some screen shots so we can get a better sense of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Gesture recognisers will only work in the view they added to. Add another one to MainVC's view to recognise gestures there.

Comment: I have a master-detail view which has many split detail view on MainVC.
Do I have to add that to all of the detail views?